# CRONtab in combination with Google Cloud VM

Tags: python-3.x, cron

I have a Google VM which I use to run some scraping scripts on. These scripts are written in Python with Selenium. Everytime I reconnect to the VM with SSH it seems I need to restart a headless browser in xvfb with the following command

```
DISPLAY=:99.0
```

Once a browser is started I can initiate the scraper; I do this by giving the whole path to the Python script.

```
python3 Code/s01-productdev/special/test/quantityScaper.py
```

I would like to automate the process of running this scraper every hour and use CRONtab to execute the script. Currently I applied the following two lines to my CRONtab file:

```
00 * * * * export DISPLAY=:99.0
01 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 Code/s01-productdev/special/test/quantityScaper.py >> logfile.out
```

Somehow cronTAB is not executing anything. The logfile named logfile.out also remains empty. Is someone familliar with how to execute daily/hourly scripts on a Google VM and how did you achieve this? Thanks in avance.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about it would be to prepend the variable to the command that cron runs as follows:
`* * * * * DISPLAY=:99.0 /path/to/the/script.py`

Another - to set the variable in /etc/environment:
`DISPLAY=:99.0`

As a last resort, you should be able to set a variable right in the cron file itself the same way as with /etc/environment, just add it in the very beginning of the file:
`DISPLAY=:99.0`

Here is a good [article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) on environment variables.